# enforce case-insensitive value for unique key constraint in cosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, unique-constraint, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, unique-key

we have a sql container. We’d like to enforce case-insensitive unique constraint on a particular property (say, ‘Name’. if a document's Name is ‘ALICE’, no other document in that logical partition shall have ‘alice’ as Name).
One solution might be introducing another property LowerCaseName and enforce the natively supported unique key config on path /LowerCaseName. Every time Name is updated, we make sure LowerCaseName is always updated as the lower-case version of Name in the same request.

I’m not sure if this is the best practice for this problem? Thanks.

```
public MyDocumentModel
{
    string Name {get; set;}

    string LowerCaseName {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys):

> In Azure Cosmos DB's SQL (Core) API, items are stored as JSON values.
> **These JSON values are case sensitive. When you choose a property as a
> unique key, you can insert case sensitive values for that property.**
> For example, If you have a unique key defined on the name property,
> "Gaby" is different from "gaby" and you can insert both into the
> container.

Based on this, I believe your approach for having a 2nd property to enforce unique key is correct.

Comment: thanks. i also believe my approach will work. just wanna brainstorm if there's any simpler solution.